# why it is wrong to nested loop of while and while or for?

Tags: linux

In my project, i use linux shell to fetch some data.

I found a error when i ran the script.

I write a test.sh to test my code:

```
[john@node04 findApp]$ cat test.sh 
 while read line
 do
   echo $line
   while read Row
   do
   done < daysnameFiles
 done < allUserAppIn
```

when i ran the test code, i got syntax error

```
[john@node04 findApp]$ sh test.sh 
 test.sh: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
 test.sh: line 6: `   done < daysnameFiles'
```

I have tried another way to use for:

```
while read line 
do
  rslInfo=$line
  for j in $(cat daysnameFiles)
  do
   echo "test"
  done
done < allUserAppIn
```

I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do 'something' in the inner loop.

```
while read line
do
  echo $line
  while read Row
  do
    echo "here"
  done < daysnameFiles
done < allUserAppIn
```